# Loop through a table with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

Trying to scrape data out of a table on a website. I got the following PHP written but it isn't working.

Following error received: **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in DataScraping.php on line 27**

```
//Sets the HTML DOM Library
require_once 'C:/xampp/php/lib/SimpleHTMLDOM/simple_html_dom.php';

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/british-airways-ba-baw');

foreach($html->find('table[id=tbl-datatable]') as $datatable) {

    foreach($datatable->find('tr') as $tr) {

        foreach($tr->find('td') as $td) {

            if(strpos($td->find('a', 0)->href, 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/') !== false) {

                echo $td->find('a', 0)->innertext .", " .$td->find('a', 0)->href;

            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Also worth mentioning, this data is publically available and it is only for personal use. Please don't comment about copyright infringement - there is nothing wrong with what I want to do.

I'm simply trying to scrape the flight number only, both the inner text and the URL that sites behind it. Any help on where I'm going wrong?

Additional test provides the data I need but with the same error in between rows:

```
    foreach($html->find('table[id=tbl-datatable]') as $datatable) {

    foreach($datatable->find('tr') as $tr) {

        foreach($tr->find('td') as $td) {

            if (strpos($td->find('a', 0)->href, '/data/flights/') !== false) {

                $test = $td->find('a', 0)->href;
                $test2 = $td->find('a', 0)->innertext;
                echo $test .", " .$test2;

            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, so which of those lines is line 27?

Comment: The echo after the if statement.

Comment: I'm surprised the if statement evaluates true (but it must if you're seeing that error); when I view the source of that page the hrefs are all relative. Maybe I'm not understanding how SimpleHTMLDOM works.

Comment: I've made an update, which is scraping the data I need, but I get lots of the same error in between the rows. Edited main post with the new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access elements of a null reference in your `if` statement itself, because not all of the `<TD>` tags have `<A>` tags in them. When there's no `<A>` tag in `$td`, `$td->find('a', 0)` is null, so

```
$td->find('a', 0)->href
```

is just what your error message said: "trying to get [a] property of [a] non-object".

You can fix this by checking the result of `find()` for null with an `if`:

```
$atag = $td->find('a', 0)
if ($atag) {
   // ...
}
```

And you can fold this into your single `if` statement with the `&&` operator. You've got another couple problems I found when running your code:

- in the source of that site, the hrefs in the table are all relative, not absolute, so when you check for `'https://www.flightradar24.com'` you find none of them
- you're not adding a newline at the end of your `echo`

So to summarize my suggestions, something like this seems to work:

```
foreach($tr->find('td') as $td) {
    $atag = $td->find('a', 0);
    if($atag && strpos($atag->href, '/data/flights/') !== false) {
        echo $atag->innertext . ", " . $atag->href . "\n";
    }           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I noticed the issue with the hrefs, which I amended in my updated version. Good spot! It's odd, as I've done this previously in VBA, which see's the entire URL and not just part of it, from the same html element.